# How to filter array using single KEY with multiple values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```js
const usersData = [
{
  
  "count": 10,
  "customerList": [
    {
      "primarySpecialty": "Multi-Specialty Grp",
      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",
      "gender": "F",
      "graduationYear": 2001,
      "regularOfficeHours": true,
      "extendedOfficeHours": true
    },
    {
      "primarySpecialty": "Family Practice",
      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",
      "gender": "F",
      "graduationYear": 2001,
      "regularOfficeHours": true,
      "extendedOfficeHours": true
    },
    {
      "primarySpecialty": "General Medicine",
      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",
      "gender": "F",
      "graduationYear": 2001,
      "regularOfficeHours": true,
      "extendedOfficeHours": true
    },
    {
      "primarySpecialty": "Internal Medicine",
      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",
      "gender": "F",
      "graduationYear": 2001,
      "regularOfficeHours": true,
      "extendedOfficeHours": true
    },
    {
      "primarySpecialty": "Internal Medicine",
      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",
      "gender": "F",
      "graduationYear": 2001,
      "regularOfficeHours": true,
      "extendedOfficeHours": true
    },
    {
      "primarySpecialty": "Multi-Specialty Grp",
      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",
      "gender": "M",
      "graduationYear": 2001,
      "regularOfficeHours": true,
      "extendedOfficeHours": true
    },
    {
      "primarySpecialty": "Multi-Specialty Grp",
      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",
      "gender": "M",
      "graduationYear": 2001,
      "regularOfficeHours": true,
      "extendedOfficeHours": true
    },
    {
      "primarySpecialty": "Family Practice",
      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",
      "gender": "M",
      "graduationYear": 2001,
      "regularOfficeHours": true,
      "extendedOfficeHours": true
    },
    {
      "primarySpecialty": "Multi-Specialty Grp",
      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",
      "gender": "F",
      "graduationYear": 2001,
      "regularOfficeHours": true,
      "extendedOfficeHours": true
    },
    {
      "primarySpecialty": "Multi-Specialty Grp",
      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",
      "gender": "M",
      "graduationYear": 2001,
      "regularOfficeHours": true,
      "extendedOfficeHours": true
    }
    
  ]
}
]

let filterKeyName = ['gender','regularOfficeHours','primarySpecialty']
let filterValue = ['M',true,'Family Practice']
let filteredProviderData = usersData[0].customerList.filter(function(e) {
  return filterKeyName.every(function(a) {
    return filterValue.includes(e[a])
  })
})
console.log(filteredProviderData)
```

Here there is a sample data for the users.
Here my requirement is to filter the key with multiple values.
here once you run the code using filterKeyName and filterValue as shown below

```
let filterKeyName = ['gender','regularOfficeHours','primarySpecialty']
let filterValue = ['M',true,'Family Practice']
```

you will get the output as displayed here.

```
[
  {
    "primarySpecialty": "Family Practice",
    "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",
    "gender": "M",
    "graduationYear": 2001,
    "regularOfficeHours": true,
    "extendedOfficeHours": true
  }
]
```

Here my requirement is to filter single key with multiple values means 
`if primarySpecialty = ['Family Practice','General Medicine']` and `Gender = ['F','M']` how to filter the usersData as shown into the code snippet.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This looks straight forward - just use those values you show (it's just 'is thing in array' for which `.indexOf` exists) in a function that you use with [`usersData.customerList.filter(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to decide whether an object matches or not? That should be more than enough of a hint for you to write the rest of the code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the current key and its index in order to make the desired comparison:

```
return e[k] === filterValue[i];
```

```js
const usersData = [{    "count": 10,  "customerList": [    {      "primarySpecialty": "Multi-Specialty Grp",      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",      "gender": "F",      "graduationYear": 2001,      "regularOfficeHours": true,      "extendedOfficeHours": true    },    {      "primarySpecialty": "Family Practice",      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",      "gender": "F",      "graduationYear": 2001,      "regularOfficeHours": true,      "extendedOfficeHours": true    },    {      "primarySpecialty": "General Medicine",      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",      "gender": "F",      "graduationYear": 2001,      "regularOfficeHours": true,      "extendedOfficeHours": true    },    {      "primarySpecialty": "Internal Medicine",      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",      "gender": "F",      "graduationYear": 2001,      "regularOfficeHours": true,      "extendedOfficeHours": true    },    {      "primarySpecialty": "Internal Medicine",      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",      "gender": "F",      "graduationYear": 2001,      "regularOfficeHours": true,      "extendedOfficeHours": true    },    {      "primarySpecialty": "Multi-Specialty Grp",      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",      "gender": "M",      "graduationYear": 2001,      "regularOfficeHours": true,      "extendedOfficeHours": true    },    {      "primarySpecialty": "Multi-Specialty Grp",      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",      "gender": "M",      "graduationYear": 2001,      "regularOfficeHours": true,      "extendedOfficeHours": true    },    {      "primarySpecialty": "Family Practice",      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",      "gender": "M",      "graduationYear": 2001,      "regularOfficeHours": true,      "extendedOfficeHours": true    },    {      "primarySpecialty": "Multi-Specialty Grp",      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",      "gender": "F",      "graduationYear": 2001,      "regularOfficeHours": true,      "extendedOfficeHours": true    },    {      "primarySpecialty": "Multi-Specialty Grp",      "primarySpecialtyCode": "008",      "gender": "M",      "graduationYear": 2001,      "regularOfficeHours": true,      "extendedOfficeHours": true    }      ]}]

let filterKeyName = ['gender','regularOfficeHours','primarySpecialty']
let filterValue = ['M',true,'Family Practice']
let filteredProviderData = usersData[0].customerList.filter(function(e) {
  return filterKeyName.every(function(k, i) {
    return e[k] === filterValue[i];
  })
})
console.log(filteredProviderData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: let filterKeyName = ['gender','regularOfficeHours','primarySpecialty']
let filterValue = ['F',true,'Family Practice','Internal Medicine']
If I am using filterValue like this its not filtering

It should be filtered using key primarySpeciality and value = ['Family Practice','Internal Medicine'] as per the filterValue